# How is graphene electrically conductive?

Tags: carbon-allotropes, carbon-family, electrical-properties

I've been doing some research into graphene for a project I'm working on, and have found that it can potentially be as strong as or even stronger than current superconductors. However, from my current understanding, a substance can only be electrically conductive if it has any free-flowing electrons or ions in its structure, and graphene doesn't have any. Its structure involves a carbon atom bonding with three other carbon atoms, though one of the bonds is a double bond meaning there are no free electrons. How does it conduct electricity then?
A google search just gives results on graphite and how it has a delocalised electron (due to its different bonding) that allows conductivity.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You have it all backwards. The bonding in graphene is no different from graphite, with its free-flowing electrons and all.

Comment: First refresh graphite. Then we might think of how/why a 2-D sheet of graphene is different from itself as constituent of graphite.

Comment: Thanks both of you. What I don't understand is why graphene shouldn't have a double bond as in this website: https://www.graphene-info.com/graphene-structure-and-shape.

Answer (score 1):

**Graphene and graphite have delocalised electrons**

The root of your misunderstanding appears to be the assumptions that the bonding in structures like graphene can be accurately represented by drawing single and double bonds. While drawing such structures makes counting electrons easy (and *drawing* such structures easy), it does not explain what is happening with the electrons.

The idea of *delocalisation* is one you don't seem to have understood. So it is worth explaining the far simpler case of benzene which is where it started.

We normally draw benzene like this:

[image: benzene pic with numbers]

This allows counting of the electrons involved (each line allows two electrons so there are 6 in total in the double bonds). But this structure implies that the molecule contains two *different* types of bond. The bond between carbons 1 and 2 is a single bond the bond between 2 and 3 is a double bond. Unfortunately this is **not** the structure of benzene.

In reality, all the bonds in benzene are the *same*. And those bonds are about halfway between single and double bonds in length. The simple picture doesn't capture reality.

More sophisticated accounts can explain this but the only important point to note is that those 6 electrons are *delocalised* over all six carbons. Some chemists like to draw benzene like this to represent that feature,:

[image: benzene with circle]

But this view makes it hard to count the electrons if you need to do that.

The important thing about the real structure is that it involves *delocalised* electrons which has big implications for the electronic behavior of benzene.

The reason why this matters for graphite and graphene (planes of graphite are exactly the same as graphene) is that the same feature occurs there. In both substances a single layer is like a bunch of fused benzene rings with the same delocalisation of the double bond electrons. But the delocalisation isn't limited to a single ring but occurs over the whole plane. We could draw a small part like this:

[image: graphene part]

to emphasise the delocalisation. An this is, in one sense, better than the typical pictures of the structure containing localised single bonds. But again means we lose count of the total electrons.

The important thing is to not take the drawings with isolated single bonds too seriously. All the bonds are the same in the real structure and all have bond orders between those os single and double bonds. But, more importantly for the question, those "extra" electrons are completely delocalised over the *whole* plane of the flat structure. They are not tied to the notional location of the double bonds.

And the fact that the electrons are delocalised means that *in that plane* they can conduct electricity (not that conductivity perpendicular to the plane is orders of magnitude lower).

Answer (score 0):

Graphene is simply one atomic layer of graphite – a layer of sp2 bonded carbon atoms arranged in a hexagonal or honeycomb lattice. Graphite is a commonly found mineral and is composed of many layers of graphene.

In graphene, each carbon atom is covalently bonded to 3 others. This atom contains free ‘delocalised’ electrons that can carry and pass on an electric charge.

Graphene does conduct electricity. This is because of its structure. In graphene, each carbon atom is covalently bonded to 3 others. There is always a fourth atom free atom. This atom contains free ‘delocalised’ electrons that can carry and pass on an electric charge.

Comment: I see. On this website, however, graphene is shown to have a double bond (unlike graphene). https://www.graphene-info.com/graphene-structure-and-shape
Also, from what I know, isn't the purpose of covalent bonds to achieve a full valence shell? In that sense, wouldn't one double bond and two single bonds between carbons make more sense for graphene?

Comment: @IAA do you know benzene and electron delocalisation? If so, in graphene you have something similar but in a 2D sheet instead of a single cell

Comment: Thanks @Alchimista. That's the biggest lead I have on it now. I don't know anything about benzene and electron delocalisation as I had thought due to it being stable there would be no delocalised electrons.

Comment: That's fine.. understand delocalisation concept through simple molecules like benzene then graphene would just be a piece of cake :)